# how to replace an N/A value coming from data source into timestamp field on snowflake using iff in a select query

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Unfortunately, we are receiving some 'n/a' values from data source for fields having type as timestamp.

We tried to replace `n/a` values with other related timestamp fields that have values:

```
iff(field1 = 'n/a', field2, field1)
```

but there was an error:

> timestamp 'n/a' is not recognized.

we tried then with:

```
ifnull(field1, field2)
```

it worked when value is NULL and not `n/a`.

Comment: Data type is checked before any operation, between any operations (triggers, query), after all operations. So your `if` have not been executed - the datatype incorrectness was detected before this. Fix your datasource. If you use LOAD DATA for importing - use preprocessing.

Comment: it is not possible to fix it from data source side as we don't have an access.

Comment: @Akina it is not possible for now.

Comment: *it is not possible to fix it from data source side as we don't have an access.* Do you receive this data via pipe? and no hard copy (file) of this data?

Comment: we are moving it as it from source within an API which does not contain anyway to clean from source that's why we are doing the cleaning within snowflake. @Akina

Comment: If so then receive this data into some intermediate storage (temptable, for example), process each row and fix incorrect data. As a palliative disable strict mode - incorrect value wil be truncated and converted to NULL, warning instead of error will be generated.

Comment: Are you using Snowflake or mysql? You've tagged both.

Comment: @SimonD I removed `mysql` from the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Snowflake then you can use `try_to_timestamp` and `ifnull` like this:

```sql
create or replace transient table test_table (field1 varchar, field2 varchar);
insert into test_table values ('n/a', '2021-01-01'), ('2021-02-01', '2021-02-02');

select 
    ifnull(try_to_timestamp(field1), field2)
from test_table;
```

**Results**
[image]

If you are using mysql I'm sure there is some equivalent expression you can use.